# JSON to html table horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: expected output in this format]

how do i combine two html tables into a single html table horizontally like table in the attached image.

This code generates two separate html table,
the JSON and Javascript code below :

This is the JSON i get :

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Total price": 20000.0,
        "Capacity": "182",
        "id": 126,
        "Total Sold": 200.0,
        "Not Sold": "300",
        "user_name": "USER 001",
        "Sold": "200",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "1499.00",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 0.0,
        "Capacity": "71",
        "id": 126,
        "Total Sold": 0.0,
        "Not Sold": "500",
        "user_name": "USER 001",
        "Sold": "0",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "99.00",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 10000.0,
        "Capacity": "347",
        "id": 127,
        "Total Sold": 100.0,
        "Not Sold": "400",
        "user_name": "USER 100",
        "Sold": "100",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "999.00",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 10000.0,
        "Capacity": "347",
        "id": 127,
        "Total Sold": 100.0,
        "Not Sold": "400",
        "user_name": "USER 100",
        "Sold": "100",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "999.00",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    }
]
}
```

HTML AND Javascript CODE used to generate the table :

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="ul-tabs">

</ul>
</div>

<script>
const setTables = new Set();
    $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
        let table;
        var row = $("<tr/>");
        if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length){
          table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
        }
        else{
          table = $('<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered"></table>');
          table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);
        }
        if(!setTables.has(value.id)){
          table.append( $("<thead><tr><th></th><th>Capacity</th><th>price per head</th><th>ActualPrice</th><th>Sold</th><th>Not Sold</th><th>Total Sold</th><th>Total Price</th></tr></thead>") );
        }
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Name));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Capacity));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["price per head"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.ActualPrice));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Sold));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Not Sold"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Total Sold"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Total price"]));
        table.append(row);            
        /*console.log(table);*/
        if(!setTables.has(value.id)) {
          setTables.add(value.id);
          $( "#ul-tabs" ).append("<li><a href=\"#tabs-"+ value.id +"\">"+value.user_name+"</a></li>");
          $( "#tabs" ).append("<div id=\"tabs-"+value.id+"\">"+table.prop('outerHTML')+"</div>");
        }
      });
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  </script>
```

So,  how do i make into a single table, attached a image of how the should look like after merging these two tables.

Comment: And by vertically you mean horizontally?

Comment: sorry , its horizontally

Comment: @deepakmurthy see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a table for each users so you need to test if the user has a table if not create that table, after that you simply append the data to that user's table, i used here the user name as a class to identify each user table:

```js
var data = {
"data": [
    {
        "Total price": 20000.0,
        "Capacity": "182",
        "id": 126,
        "Total Sold": 200.0,
        "Not Sold": "300",
        "user_name": "USER 001",
        "Sold": "200",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "1499.00",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 0.0,
        "Capacity": "71",
        "id": 126,
        "Total Sold": 0.0,
        "Not Sold": "500",
        "user_name": "USER 001",
        "Sold": "0",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "99.00",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 10000.0,
        "Capacity": "347",
        "id": 127,
        "Total Sold": 100.0,
        "Not Sold": "400",
        "user_name": "USER 100",
        "Sold": "100",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "999.00",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Total price": 10000.0,
        "Capacity": "347",
        "id": 127,
        "Total Sold": 100.0,
        "Not Sold": "400",
        "user_name": "USER 100",
        "Sold": "100",
        "price per head": 100,
        "ActualPrice": "999.00",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    }
]
};

    $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
        let table;
        if(!$('table').hasClass(value.user_name)) {
          $('.main').append('<td><table class="'+value.user_name+'"><thead><th colspan="8">'+value.user_name+'</th><tr><th></th><th>Capacity</th><th>price per head</th><th>ActualPrice</th><th>Sold</th><th>Not Sold</th><th>Total Sold</th><th>Total Price</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table</td>');
        }
        table = $('table[class="'+value.user_name+'"] tbody');
        var row = $("<tr/>");
          

        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Name));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Capacity));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["price per head"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.ActualPrice));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.Sold));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Not Sold"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Total Sold"]));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value["Total price"]));
        table.append(row);            
        /*console.log(table);*/

      });
```

```css
td td,td th {outline:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="ul-tabs">
<table><tbody><tr class="main"></tr></tbody></table>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this creates two separate table, need somewhat like append the 2nd table next to 1st table horizontally. i have atttached a screenshot of it.

Comment: so you want the 2 tables in a bigger table?

Comment: 2 tables in a single table horizontally

Comment: cool:) this is what i was looking for, is there a way i can remove 2nd tables 1st column that is only ABC and XYZ

Comment: short answer is yes